# Client channel unusable after a network reset

Tags: c++, grpc

**Summary: If a client channel is in a `READY` state and the network is disconnected, the channel becomes unusable and the client will not attempt to reconnect to the server once the network connection is re-established. The channel does not transition from a `READY` state to a `TRANSIENT_FAILURE` on a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error (deadline set by my client application).**

**What version of gRPC and what language are you using?**

1.17.2
Same issue experience in version 1.11.x
C++

**What operating system (Linux, Windows,...) and version?**

Client running on Ubuntu 16.04.
Server running Windows Enterprise.

**What did you do?**

Server and client are both started on a connected network. I can successfully make calls and receive responses from the server. When the network is turned off, the server receives a `"Disconnected client - Endpoint read failed"` error. Some other relevant fields in this debug message - `"grpc_status":14 (UNAVAILABLE), "occured_during_write":0, "description":"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"`.

At the time of network disconnect, the client does not print out any logs at all (using `GRPC_TRACE=connectivity_state,call_error,op_failure,server_channel,client_channel,channel GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG`).

Once the network is turned on again there are no logs experienced on neither the server nor the client. Attempting to make a call using the client (send a launch request) results in a repeated `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error. Turning off the network connection at this time does not result in a server side `"Disconnected client"` error.

The client context is set to use a deadline (tested with 2 and 10 seconds). Synchronous calls are used in this case.

**Code sniplets:**

/rpc_service.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/rpc/status.proto";

message RpcRequest {
}

message RpcResponse {
}

service RpcService{
rpc Call(RpcRequest) returns (RpcResponse);
}
```

/client.cc

Initialization:

```
std::unique_ptrRpcService::Stub stub_ = RpcService::NewStub(::grpc::CreateChannel(
server_endpoint, ::grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
```

Sending a rpc request:

```
::grpc::ClientContext context;
context.set_deadline(
gpr_time_from_micros(call_timeout_.InMicroseconds(), GPR_TIMESPAN));
RpcRequest request;
RpcResponse response;
::grpc::Status grpc_status = stub_->Call(&context, request, &response);
```

/server.cc

```
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
builder.AddListeningPort(endpoint, ::grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
builder.RegisterService(&rpc_service);
std::unique_ptrgrpc::Server grpc_server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
```

**What did you expect to see?**

Client should make a successful call after a network reset.

**What did you see instead?**

Client fails to receive a response from the server.

**Anything else we should know about your project / environment?**

When the network connection is re-established and the client fails to receive a response from the server, tcpdump captures the client sending out some packets.
Starting up both client and server with network ON, and then unplugging the network does not result in any error messages until a call is attempted. This is the same result as when starting both client and server with the network disconnected. Once a call is attempted the client will transition from `IDLE` to `CONNECTING` and then begin to bounce back and forth between `CONNECTING` and `TRANSIENT_FAILURE` states (attempting to reconnect with exponential back-off) until the connection is re-established.

If the client is started with the network connected, but doesn't send a request and the network is disconnected the server doesn't get a disconnected client error. Until a call is made, the client stays in a `"IDLE"`.

If a client is initialized and a call is made on a disconnected network, then the client will enter a `CONNECTING` state (with exponential backoff up to a max of 2 min where the client will be in a `TRANSIENT_FAILURE` state). Once the network is connected, the connection will be re-established the next time the channel will enter a `CONNECTING` state and the client will enter the `READY` state. After this, each call will succeed until the network is reset.
Disconnecting the network after the client is in a `READY` state will not transition the client out of a `READY` state.

In summary: Until a call is made, the client will stay in an `"IDLE"` state no matter the network status. Once a call is made, the client will attempt to make a connection by entering the `CONNECTING` state. If no connection is found, it will transition bounce in-between `CONNECTING` and `TRANSIENT_FAILURE` states. Once a connection is found, the client will go into a `READY` state. From here, if a connection is lost, the client will not attempt to enter a `CONNECTING` state again.

**Similar issue (closed) to the one I’m having:**

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16974

**Known fix:**

Create a new channel on each call.

**Failed fix attempts:**

```
Set GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MAX_PINGS_WITHOUT_DATA = 0
```

**Questions:**

Should the client be able to use the already created channel after a network reset?

Does the channel have to be restarted when a network is reset?

**Note:** I opened a ticket on the grpc github and haven't received a response in 5 days, so I'm posting here as well. Link to grpc github issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18554

Comment: yup, and you will get zero response for such a detailed question after a year and 4 months